# How can I zerofill the /swapfile without wiping out what makes it a swapfile?

Tags: ubuntu, swap

I have a script that I run in order to optimize the disk space prior to backing up a virtual guest (really doesn't matter too much which hypervisor is used).

Modern Ubuntu versions (e.g. 18.04) seem to default to using a `/swapfile` rather than a partition for the purpose. That's fine, too.

However, I'd like to zerofill the swap file along with the root partition containing it.

With swap *partitions* this was relatively painless as there was always a way to extract the existing `$UUID` from the swap partition and - after zerofilling the partition - run `mkswap -U $UUID` to re-create said swap partition.

However, with the `/swapfile` I don't see how to do that. While I realize that you can't mount a `/swapfile` by UUID in `/etc/fstab`, I'd still want to retain the UUID.

So I reckon need one of the following to proceed:

1. I need a method that can zerofill the swap file without also wiping those structures that make it a swap partition (i.e. avoid having to run `mkswap -U $UUID`)
2. I need a method to retrieve the existing UUID from a swap *file* (as opposed to a partition where I can use anything from `blkid` to looking at `/dev/disk/by-uuid/$UUID` ...)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

1. This won’t clear the swap file as thoroughly as re-creating it, but if you clear it after skipping the first 4KiB (strictly speaking, the first page, which depends on your architecture), you won’t touch any of the structures which identify a swap file.
2. `blkid` works fine on swap files too:

   ```
   $ mkswap swap
   Setting up swapspace version 1, size = 512 MiB (536866816 bytes)
   no label, UUID=7916b81f-1faa-4b7d-84ef-b0bf2f75dbbc

   $ blkid swap
   swap: UUID="7916b81f-1faa-4b7d-84ef-b0bf2f75dbbc" TYPE="swap"
   ```

The header format is [defined in the kernel](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/include/linux/swap.h#n97): the old format has a magic value at the end of the first page, the new format combines that with a 1KiB free area, then a number of fields (version, size, bad pages, UUID, label) which all fit comfortably inside the first page.

Comment: Wow, hands down the fastest answer I ever received on any StackExchange site. Thanks. I frankly never used `blkid` with a parameter. Guess I should be doing that rather than, for example, using `dd` with an offset.

Comment: Right, reading the UUID and re-creating the swap file is probably the easier option.

Comment: @0xC0000022L also look into the output format options of `blkid`. Depending on the version, you might be able to do `blkid swap -o value -s uuid` to extract just the UUID.

Comment: @muru thanks, already did and opted for `blkid -o export <file>` which I pipe through `sed` to prepend `local ` to each line and then `eval` using Bash. This way I have the values in my function as local environment variables right away.